# What are those x: identifiers called in rails?

Tags: ruby

When do we use a colon after an identifier in ruby? for eg:

```
<%= f.input :XML, as: :file, wrapper: :vertical_file_input %>
```

here we have `as:` but for `f.input` we don't have a colon.

What are those `x:` identifiers known as? and how do we decide whether to put a colon or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar.

```
{as: :file, wrapper: :vertical_file_input}
```

is a Hash, equal to

```
{:as=>:file, :wrapper=>:vertical_file_input}
```

I personally don't find the first version more readable.

So `x:` is just `:x` (a Symbol) as key in a hash.

```
f.input :XML, as: :file, wrapper: :vertical_file_input
```

is the method "input" called on object f, with :XML as first parameter and {:as=>:file, :wrapper=>:vertical_file_input} as second parameter. You could also write it :

```
f.input(:XML, {as: :file, wrapper: :vertical_file_input})
```

This kind of method call is very common in Rails.